# Unpad all-zero rows from the end of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this line:

```
x = np.zeros((10, 2), int)
```

and a for loop that fills this for the first 6 elements.
Is there a way to remove the remaining 0 elements?

Comment: What are 6 first element of 2d array? For 1d it is obvious but for multi dimensional the meaning of "first" requires some clarification?

Comment: My array fills as coordinate points x coordinate goes in x[i,0] and the y coordinate as x[i,1]

Comment: So the result's shape should be (6,2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the last all zero rows:

```
x = x[:(np.where(x.any(axis=1))[0]).max()+1]
```

example:

x:

```
[[1 2]
 [0 0]
 [1 2]
 [0 0]]
```

output:

```
[[1 2]
 [0 0]
 [1 2]]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = x[:6]
```

Note that this solution will create 6 element long view to original array. Modifying view will modify original array.